# Angular Datatable - Property 'AppComponent' does not exist on type 'ColumnSettings'

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-datatables

I have imported the AppComponent in my another TS file, like below

```
import { AppComponent } from 'src/app/app.component';

constructor(
    public AppComponent: AppComponent
) {}
```

I want to use this class from one of my column render functions. I'm not been able to access it like below:

```
columns: [
{
    render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
    if (this.AppComponent.checkModulePermission('subadmin', 'sub_admin', 'view')) { // error coming as Property 'AppComponent' does not exist on type 'ColumnSettings'.ts(2339)
        //my_code_goes_here
    }
]
```

Comment: This is the job for a `service` (providedIn: 'root').

Answer (score 0):

Inside constructor you cannot access component like this. constructor parameters are mainly used to get the dependent objects for the component from the dependency injection hierarchy.

Better to move the `checkModulePermission` function from AppComponent to a service and inject the service to any .ts file.

Comment: thank you for your help, just for clarification, how the class of that service will be used? as I need to use the imported class from the render function

Comment: In angular when ever we use @Injectable() decorator to any class. angular will create an instance of the class on runtime. we can access these instance by simply referring the service class in the class constructor. It is simple. [refer here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/angular-dependency-injection/) to know more about this.